# Why getAnnotatedParameterTypes does not see annotations for array type?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

For some reason I don't understand why this code prints `true` and `false`, what is special about array that it does not include that annotation here?

It works as expected if you use `getParameters` instead.

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@interface Lel {
}

class Test {
    public static void a(@Lel String args) {}
    public static void b(@Lel String[] args) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("a", String.class)
            .getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0].isAnnotationPresent(Lel.class));
        System.out.println(Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("b", String[].class)
            .getAnnotatedParameterTypes()[0].isAnnotationPresent(Lel.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the annotated type `@Lel String[]`, the annotation applies to the element type `String`. To annotate the array type, you would use `String @Lel []`.

The JLS contains some examples like this in [§9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4):

> Type annotations can apply to an array type or any component type thereof ([§10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)). For example, assuming that `A`, `B`, and `C` are annotation types meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`, then given the field declaration:
>
> ```
> @C int @A [] @B [] f;
> ```
>
> `@A` applies to the array type `int[][]`, `@B` applies to its component type `int[]`, and `@C` applies to the element type `int`. For more examples, see [§10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2).
>
> An important property of this syntax is that, in two declarations that differ only in the number of array levels, the annotations to the left of the type refer to the same type. For example, `@C` applies to the type `int` in all of the following declarations:
>
> ```
> @C int f;
> @C int[] f;
> @C int[][] f;
> ```

Also, `getParameters()` will work to retrieve the annotation(s) if the way that your annotation is declared allows it to target the parameter declaration itself, as well as the type. JLS §9.7.4 explains in more detail the conditions under which an annotation is determined to target a type, declaration or both.

Comment: Oh, didn't think about checking specification here, and I didn't find clear answer in javadocs, thanks!

Comment: I’m glad the spec gives a clear example, but I find that syntax rather unsettling.  The lesson I take from this is: plan on never using type annotations with array types.